# HTML CSS, Background Image Won't Load

Tags: html, css

My background image for the div won't load in even thou everything is correct, it'll only load when I type something on it.

HTML Code ~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Oswald&family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="Header">



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
body {

    background-color: #FEF991;
    margin: 0px;
    paddng: 0px;

}

#Header {

    background-image: url("A.png");

}
```

The files are correct and everything but it'll only load in when I write something I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Comment: is `A.png` located within an image folder or main project directory? Also you may want to give some width and height dimensions to `#header`

Answer (score 2):

The container will compute to a 0px if there are no explicit dimensions provided for it or content.  Applying a height to your #Header element will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your header doesn't have height or width, and by default it will not be displayed until you add some HTML elements to it or adding style `height` and `width`, try adding this to header style:

```
#Header {
    background-image: url("A.png");
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

working snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FEF991;
  margin: 0px;
  paddng: 0px;

}

#Header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Oswald&family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="Header">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad to help, please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find any of the answers useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the div's height is 0%. whenever you add some text to it, div's size increases and so you are able to see the background image.